# JQuery / Gridster Any Working Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridster

I have been looking for a basic working example of the Gridster.js Drag and Drop Functionality, but I have tried 3 different samples online and cant seem to get them working for me either locally or after FTP.

My Source code is here http://hcs-it.com/gridster.html

Please can anyone help get me started on this, I have ordered a book on Functionality and looking forward to reading but would like to make a start on this project in next day or two.

Thanks Guys! Forever Helpful

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try their website directly:

http://gridster.net/

They have excellent documentation, and a series of demos covering a variety of scenarios.

Looks like you are using jQuery 2.1.3, while they are using 1.10.2. As jQuery is the primary dependency for gridster.js I would use the same version that they are using in their demo examples.

Use

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or download the correct version directly

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tuipopenoe/jnhb3yp2/

Comment: I changed my JQuery version to v1.11.2 which is available on their site, but cant seem to get any source. Cant Even seem to get my js Button Click to work.?

Comment: Tried this Sample which works great for them http://gridster.net/demos/custom-drag-handle.

However, I have copied the Source from CSS and JS and HTML, but mine looks like this . http://hcs-it.com/gridster.html

Just Cant understand Why ??

Comment: It is failing to load your local copy of gridster.js. Why not use a cdn and save the bandwidth? Try 
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.gridster/0.5.6/jquery.gridster.min.css"></script>`

Comment: OK, Thanks for this. But changed that now and still not working. How are you debugging this?

Comment: Chrome developer's console. Press f12 while viewing your page in Chrome.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: Got it !!!  Changed the CDN Too https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.gridster/0.5.6/jquery.gridster.js as the one above didnt work. That's fantastic, Cheers Bro